# Querying one-to-many relation further linked by other tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Sorry I can't think of a better generic title for this. I am building a photo voting app using pyramid and sqlalchemy. Full schema and orm is at the end, but the most relevant information are

1. `photo` table
2. `vote` table with `photo_id` and `user_id`, where the latter identifies the user who voted up or down the photo.
3. `category` table with the list of photo categories
4. `photocategory` table linking `photo` and `category` tables

In the app's main photo feed I would like to show the photos in the following order

1. photos that the user has NOT voted first before the ones that he/she has voted
2. within each group above (not voted and then voted), sort by descending order of number of existing votes of the photos

The app will also have the flexibility to show photos from certain category only

The way I am implementing now is...

- getting only the photos for desired category

i.e.

```
photos = DBSession.query(Photos).join(photocategory, Photo.id==photocategory.c.photo_id).filter(photocategory.c.category_id==__CATEGORY_ID_HERE__).all()
```

- sort `photos` by number of votes

i.e.

```
photos = sorted(photos, key=lambda photo: len(photo.votes), reverse=True)
```

- iterating through `photos` to see if the user has already voted, and append the photo to either a `voted` or `unvoted` list/array

However, this is so inefficient because I have to search through all the photos the user has previously voted for every single photo in `photos`, so I am wondering what is the right and efficient way to do this... thanks

**SCHEMA**

```
  photo_table = schema.Table('photo', metadata,
  schema.Column('id', types.Integer,
    schema.Sequence('photo_seq_id'), primary_key=True),
  schema.Column('caption', types.UnicodeText(), nullable=True),
  schema.Column('timestamp', types.TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now()),
  schema.Column('last_updated', types.TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now(),),
  schema.Column('spam', types.Boolean, default=0),
  schema.Column('trash', types.Boolean, default=0),
  schema.Column('image_path', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False),
  schema.Column('user_id', types.Integer, schema.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
  mysql_engine='InnoDB'
)

category_table = schema.Table('category', metadata,
  schema.Column('id', types.Integer,
    schema.Sequence('category_seq_id'), primary_key=True),
  schema.Column('name', types.Unicode(255), nullable=False, unique=True),
  mysql_engine='InnoDB'
)

photocategory_table = schema.Table('photocategory', metadata,
  schema.Column('photo_id', types.Integer, schema.ForeignKey('photo.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),
  schema.Column('category_id', types.Integer, schema.ForeignKey('category.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), primary_key=True),
  mysql_engine='InnoDB'
)

vote_table = schema.Table('vote', metadata,
  schema.Column('id', types.Integer,
    schema.Sequence('vote_seq_id'), primary_key=True),
  schema.Column('timestamp', types.TIMESTAMP(), default=datetime.now()),
  schema.Column('upvote', types.Boolean, nullable=False),
  schema.Column('photo_id', types.Integer, schema.ForeignKey('photo.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
  schema.Column('user_id', types.Integer, schema.ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='CASCADE')),
  mysql_engine='InnoDB'
)
```

**ORM Mapper**

```
orm.mapper(Photo, photo_table, properties={
  'votes': orm.relation(Vote, backref='photo', lazy='dynamic'),
  'categories': orm.relation(Category, secondary=photocategory_table, backref='photos'),
})

orm.mapper(User, user_table, properties={
  'photos': orm.relation(Photo, backref='owner'),
  'votes': orm.relation(Vote, backref='voter', lazy='dynamic'),
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doing this using SQL itself is a better idea. The following is untested and will probably not work, but you can tweak it to suit your needs

You can select the photos of a category by

```
cat_photos = session.query(PhotoCategory.photo_id.label('pid')).options(lazyload('*')).filter(PhotoCategory.category_id==SOMEID).subquery()
```

Joining user and photo table to get a list of photos on which a user can vote. Assuming a user cannot vote on his own photo, you get

```
elig_photos = session.query(User).join(Photos,Photos.user_id!=User.id).options(lazyload('*')).with_entities(Photos.id.label('pid'),User.id.label('uid').subquery()
```

Now you can left join this to the votes table and your subquery to get the photos of a particular category  on which the user has not yet voted

```
not_voted = session.query(elig_photos).outerjoin(Votes,and_(Votes.photo_id==elig_photos.c.pid,Votes.user_id==elig_photos.c.uid)).join(cat_photos,cat_photos.c.pid==elig_photos.c.pid).with_entities(elig_photos.c.pid.label('photo_id'),Votes.upvote.label('upvote')).options(lazyload('*')).filter(User.id==SOMEUSER).filter(Votes.upvote==None).all()
```

Get the photos of this category sorted by number of votes. We will have to do a left join because there may be some photos for which no one has voted yet

```
sorted_votes = session.query(cat_photos).outerjoin(Votes,cat_photos.c.pid==Votes.photo_id).with_entities(cat_photos.c.pid.label('pid'),func.coalesce(func.sum(Votes.upvote),0).label('sum_votes')).options(lazyload('*')).group_by(cat_photos.pid).order_by(desc('sum_votes')).all()
```

NOTE - I have added an aoption `options(lazyload('*'))` to each query to make the relationships lazy loading

Now you have two lists -

- `sorted_votes` which lists the photos of this category in descending
  order of votes (0 votes for photos that have not been voted by anyone)
- `not_voted` which lists the photos of this category not voted upon by user

Note that the photos of this category uploaded by user will be a part of the first list

You can process the two lists in python to display not_voted first based on their indexes in the first list and then display the rest of the first list as it is

```
not_voted_sorted = sorted(not_voted,key=lambda x:sorted_votes.index(x))
rest_of_the_photos = [y for y in sorted_votes if y not in not_voted]
```

It would be a good idea (IMO) if you only get the photo_ids from these queries. The entire Photo object list can be fetched separately from DB and kept in a dictionary with photo_id being the key. Thus in the template you can display the entire photo detail if you know what photo_id you want ot show.

Final NOTE: If something doesn't work, try to write a plain SQL for what you are trying to do, then write the SQLAlchemy equivalent and print the statement to compare if your hand-written SQL and SQLAlchemy generated SQL are the same or not